# Textbox value not updated after postback happens on the page

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview with a few text box on it in an ASP .Net Web Application. The textbox is populated with values from sql server. I have the option on the page to switch between Companies, and PageLoad happens again and new values gets populated from sql server. The user has the option to edit the values in the textbox and on clicking update, the same will be updated on sql server.

All works fine until a postback happens somewhere on the page. After this, even if we switch between companies, the values in the textbox remains same, although on debugging, we see that new values are coming correctly from sql server. When this happens, even if the page is refreshed, the values still doesnt change.

One way in which I could resolve the issue is, by changing the textbox Id everytime, company is switched (ie tb1CompanyA to tb1CompanyB). If this is done the textbox gets its value correctly under all circumstances. But the problem is I have a few other pages, where this sort of technique cannot be used. Any idea how this can be resolved. ?

I use the below code on pageLoad. The value of dtOrginal is correct, but in the front end it shows a different value

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dtNow = sql3.IndianTime();
        DataTable dtOriginal = SetDataTable_ForGridView(dtNow);
        GridView1.DataSource = dtOriginal;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

To after switching companies to reload the page I use location.reload()

```
 

    function changedisplayname(currobj) 
    {
        var hotelselectedname = $(currobj).find('h4').find('span').text();
        var roomselectedname = $(currobj).find('p').text();
        var pathname = window.location.pathname; // Returns path only
        var isCallSuccess = "false";
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.aspx/HotelNameChange",
        data: '{HotelName: "' + hotelselectedname + '",RoomName:"' + roomselectedname + '" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
        isCallSuccess = "true";
        },
        failure: function (response) {
        isCallSuccess = "false";
        }
        });
        if (isCallSuccess == "true")
        {
        location.reload();
        }
        }
```

Comment: Not sure if it helps in this case but have you tried adding a action property to the form tag I assume you got somewhere on the site? Such as <form method="POST" action="MyPage.aspx">

Comment: Can you please post your actual code instead of describing it? It is critical to see how exactly values are set for the textbox, how is companies switch implemented, what can cause a postback that starts the trouble.

Comment: @Xariez ASP.NET WebForms has special (daft) rules all of its own - postbacks are not handled in a conventional way, and only one "form" tag is allowed in the entire page, the action method of it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: @Harish It's impossible to give you any sensible advice without seeing the relevant parts of your code. These kinds of issues often come down to detailed specifics about how you're doing things. A description is too vague - otherwise we could all write our software in prose (or even poetry??) and stop using all these tedious loops and if statements!

Comment: Ahh right, that's right. Completely forgot about that, thanks for correcting me! @ADyson

Comment: I have added my codes here as you had asked. Please help.

Comment: did you tried to use !postback in your pageload? you should not Bind it every time just on page load and you sould let ViewState handles your data

Comment: @Pauya  Yes I tried !PostBack as well.. No use

Comment: shows us the HotelNameChange method as well. IMO, doing an ajax call and then immediately reloading the whole page when it returns is an anti-pattern. You're making two trips to the server instead of one. Either do everything you need to in a single postback (via a button click event, perhaps) or use some Javascript in the "success" callback of the ajax to change the content of the page to whatever you need (the server could return the necessary data for this as the response of the ajax call). What you've got now is an inconsistent confusion of two different approaches.

Comment: And if you use the ajax route, **please** don't use `async:false`. It's well known to cause horrible user experience by locking up the browser (users often think it's crashed if the ajax request takes longer than expected). Chrome, and possibly others, have already deprecated this functionality, so you can expect it to be removed eventually. Instead, whatever action you need to take that relies on the response from ajax, take it (or call it from) the "success" callback method.

Comment: @ADyson Tried all that you suggested. Problem still persist...

Comment: Ok, sorry to hear that. However, without seeing exactly what you tried, it's difficult to help further, because I don't know whether you did all of it correctly or not.